# Leksah / Haskell : search for functions that operate on a given type (say [a], [Char])

Tags: haskell, ide, leksah

Is there an easy way to search for functions that operate on a given type , say on `[a]` ? In Leksah Haskell IDE or with some other method ?

If I want to figure out all the things that can be done to `[a]` or say `[Char]`, what should I do ?

Akin to typing `"hello".`+autocomplete in a Java/Scala IDE ?

So that all the possible operations show up that can be done to that class (i.e. class member functions) ?

Comment: There are a lot more Haskell functions that operate on lists than there are methods of any sane Java class, so I'm not sure that is going to be so useful. However, Hoogle, and I think Hayoo,  let you search by type. And I believe they're both installable locally.

Comment: Thanks, I have a look.